# If a function is continuous on a closed interval, then it is bounded on that interval.

Tags: calculus, continuity, solution-verification

So, the theorem I'm trying to prove is the following:

If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$.

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$. Suppose that $f$ is not bounded on $[a,b]$. So, there does not exist an $M > 0$ such that:

$$|f(x)| \leq M$$

for any $x \in [a,b]$. Define a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that all the terms of the sequence belong to $[a,b]$. Then, it is clear that there does not exist an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$|f(x_n)| \leq n$$

By a previously proven result, there exists a $c \in [a,b]$ such that every neighbourhood of $c$ contains infinitely many terms of the sequence. So, the function is unbounded in every neighbourhood of $c$. By another previously proven result, it follows that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ does not exist. This contradicts the continuity of $f$ as asserted by the hypothesis. It follows that $f$ must be bounded on $[a,b]$. This proves the desired result.

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, why? How can I fix it?

Comment: "Define a sequence ${x_n}$ such that all the terms of the sequence belong to $[a,b]$. Then, it is clear that..." This is false, not to mention clear. Take, for example, $x_n=a$ for all $n$. You need to improve this sequence.

Comment: Okay yea, I see the issue now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is it “clear that there does not exist an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $|f(x_n)|\leqslant n$”? Besides, what does this mean? Is it for *every* $n$ or for *some* $n$?

Suppose that $f$ is unbounded. For each $n\in\Bbb N$, take $x_n\in[a,b]$ such that $\bigl|f(x_n)\bigr|\geqslant n$; such a $x_n$ must exist, since we are assuming that $f$ is unbounded. This sequence has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ that converges to some $c\in[a,b]$. Therefore, $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})=f(c)$. But this is impossible, since every subsequence of $\bigl(f(x_n)\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is unbounded and every convergent sequence is bounded.

Comment: Dear Jose, would you please explain how it is possible to choose $x_n\in[a,b]$ with $|x_n|\geq n$?

Comment: @Qurultay I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: @ Jose: I think you mean $|f(x_n)| \ge n$ and not $|x_n| \ge n.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just had something of an alternate argument for the problem. I'm going to try editing that in and see if it works or not.

Comment: @Fred Sure! Thanks.

Comment: @AbhijeetVats So, you are going to edit your question in such a way that my answer is not an answer anymore? Don't you see anything wrong about that?

Comment: Oh okay fair enough fair enough. Never mind, lol, I tried making an alternative argument but it doesn't work

Comment: I think that a new question would be more appropriate, but I have nothing against posting it as a comment.

Comment: Wait, I don't quite understand why we need a convergent subsequence in this case? Like, the result I proved before this was that if we have a sequence $\{x_n\}$ such that all the terms are in $[a,b]$, there exists a $c \in [a,b]$ such that every neighbourhood of $c$ would have infinitely many terms in the sequence. Since i have your suggested sequence, I can just say that there exists a $c \in [a,b]$ such that every neighbourhood of $c$ contains infinitely many terms of $\{x_n\}$. Since $f$ is unbounded in every neighbourhood of $c$, doesn't the conclusion that I want follow from that?

Comment: @AbhijeetVats Yes. That will also work.

Comment: Aight, thank you so much!